# Easier way to create alphanumeric + '_' string from existing string?

Tags: c, string

Is there a better/easier way to create a `\w+` string from an existing string?

```
 char *FixName(char *name)
 {
     char *ptr, tmp;
     char *new = malloc(strlen(name)+1);
     sprintf(new, "str_");
     for (ptr = name + 4; *ptr; ptr++)
     {
         if ((*ptr >= '0' && *ptr <= '9') ||
             (*ptr >= 'A' && *ptr <= 'Z') ||
             (*ptr >= 'a' && *ptr <= 'z') ||
             *ptr == '_')
         {
             tmp = *(ptr+1);
             *(ptr+1) = '\0';
             strcat(new, ptr);
             *(ptr+1) = tmp;
         }
     }
     free(name);
     return new;
 }

 // USAGE:
 //char *j = strdup("str_[](1.00)");
 //printf("J: %s\n", j);
 //j = FixName(j);
 //printf("J: %s\n", j);
 //free(j);
 // OUTPUT:
 //J: str_[](1.00)
 //J: str_100
```

Thanks for comments, new function:

```
  void FixName(char *name)
  {
      char *ptr;
      unsigned short count = strlen("str_");
      for (ptr = name + count; *ptr; ptr++)
      {
          if ((*ptr >= '0' && *ptr <= '9') ||
              (*ptr >= 'A' && *ptr <= 'Z') ||
              (*ptr >= 'a' && *ptr <= 'z') ||
              *ptr == '_')
          {
              *(name+count) = *ptr;
              count++;
          }
      }
      *(name+count) = '\0';
  }
```

Comment: For crissake, use char literals: if (*ptr >= '@')...

Comment: Watch out for Schlemiel the Painter here, too: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000319.html

Comment: You should note that if you care about being able to compile as C++ (and you *should*), you cannot use a variable named `new`, and you need a cast to `char *` after the malloc call.

Comment: @Billy, common practise in C is that you shouldn't cast the return of `malloc`.

Comment: @Jens: Just because it is *common* does not mean that it is *good* :)

Comment: 1) You don't allocate enough room with malloc (it could easilu overrun). 2) Don't use new as a variable name. At some point somebody may want to convert it to C++ project this will just make it harder. 3) Try and use the standard library to help (strspn springs to mind)

Comment: @Billy ONeal: don't come you with just a common place yourself. Here, there is a simple and good reason for that. In C a missing header for `malloc` will make the compiler assume that the return type is `int`. Then actually the effective cast in this case here would be `(char*)(int)malloc(...)` which may have desastrous consequences. Just for that, you know. Please stop pushing C++ stuff in a C discussion. These are just different languages.

Comment: @Jens: If I was pushing C++ stuff into a C discussion I would be telling you to never ever use `malloc`, and to use smart pointers or `std::vector` instead. If you don't include the correct headers, then your code is wrong, no ifs ands or buts about it (besides, most translation units are going to have `stdlib.h` around anyway). Calling functions without prototypes is discouraged even in C89, and the default-to-int rule is removed in C99. There's no reason to write new code that cannot compile as both C and C++ (except C99 VLAs) -- think of it as doubling the potential userbase of that code.

Comment: @Billy ONeal: fact is that in C, `void*` casts to any data pointer type, this is a design feature of the language. Another fact is that people do forget to include the header. In C, an explicit cast should be only placed where it is needed to mark something like "don't worry, I know want I am doing". Systematic casts in C are simply wrong. Doubling the userbase you get with clean header files. The syntactical intersection between the two languages is full of pitfalls, since the semantics are different.

Comment: @Jens: What semantic is different? I know of 3 issues. 1. No implicit conversion from void * to other pointer types, 2. C++ reserves a few more keywords, and 3. required function prototypes. The only common use case of 1 is for malloc, and every decent C textbook (including the ANSI edition of K&R) tells you to put the cast there. 2. Not hard to avoid. 3. you should be doing that already anyway.

Comment: @Billy ONeal: This is not the place to discuss that further. But you are mistaken, C and C++ have much more differences in nasty little details than you think.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One thing you could do to immediately make your code much clearer is to use character literals:

```
if ((*ptr >= '0' && *ptr <= '9') ||
    (*ptr >= 'A' && *ptr <= 'Z') ||
    (*ptr >= 'a' && *ptr <= 'z') ||
    *ptr == '_')
```

A better solution is to use [isalnum](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cctype/isalnum/).

```
if (isalnum(*ptr) || *ptr == '_')
```

Be aware that different locales may consider different characters to be alphanumeric.

A few more issues with your code:

- You could work out the size of the string you need before allocating the memory for it, to avoid overallocating.
- You can build the result without using strcat by keeping a pointer to where you have reached so far.
- I don't like that call to `free` inside the function. You can't be sure that the string passed in as a parameter was allocated using malloc.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Mark's answer:

[`sprintf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/sprintf/) returns the number of char it wrote. You can make use of this as:

```
    count = sprintf(new, "str_");
    for (ptr = name + 4; *ptr; ptr++) {

            if ((*ptr >= '0' && *ptr <= '9') || (*ptr >= 'A' && *ptr <= 'Z') ||
                (*ptr >= 'a' && *ptr <= 'z') || *ptr == '_')
            {
                    *(new+count) = *ptr;
                    count++;
            }
    }
    *(new+count) = 0; // terminating null char
```